# my problem is my arduino don't work correctly

Tags: arduino, pyserial, arduino-uno

This is my code:

```
int data;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  Serial.println("Hi");
} 

void loop(){
  delay(500);
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    int data = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(data);
  }
  
  if (data == 1)
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  else if (data == 0)
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
}
```

Now when I run the code and send a data the arduino don't work correctly
for example:
I send `1`
and my arduino prints: `49 \n 10`
and then led don't turn ON

This is the printed text :

```
-> Hi 
-> 49
-> 10
```

And never `data == 1`

Comment: You have declared two different `data` variables. One is global, before `setup`. The second is inside the `while` loop inside `loop`. Drop the `int` declarator of the second one, so the `while` loop can use the global variable. Even better, remove them both and declare it at the top of `loop`. Finally, you are sending ASCII characters: `49` is the code for the character `1`... so either test for characters 48 49 or convert to numbers 0 1. And, you might want to read and throw away the line ending (new-line) character, value 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `data` is an `int`. Serial.read() has to fit its data into that type, so it returns the ASCII value of your input. 49 is ASCII for 1 and 10 is ASCII for LF or line feed.

To get the character you inputted, set the type of `data` to `char`. This should then return 1.

Comment: The Serial.read() returns int, so there is no problem with fitting anything. It also returns int(-1) when there are no data available. Anyway neve use magical constants like 49. Use data == '1' or data == '0' so anyone can understand your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

can you try to change your `int data` to `char data`
and use

```
if (data == '1'){
digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
}
else if (data == '0'){
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

i think if you using `int` that will convert from character to decimal from ASCII table

Answer (score 0):

you initialized the data twice the data you couldn't access the data inside you while loop

try this code

```
int data;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  Serial.println("Hi");
} 

void loop(){
  delay(500);
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    data = Serial.read();  //you don't need to initialize the data again 
  }
  
  Serial.print(data);
  
  if (data == 1)
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  else if (data == 0)
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
}
```